# ownCloud and NFS (ownCloud and RuneAudio)

Tags: linux, nfs, owncloud

I have two home servers running, one with ownCloud, and one with RuneAudio. The idea is for RuneAudio to be able to access the music stored on ownCloud. Since RuneAudio can connect to drives via sambda or NFS, I though about doing the following:

1. create a `music` account on ownCloud, where I will upload (or move) my music folder
2. create a link `some_path/music` to `data/music/files/` on the ownCloud machine (or not)
3. add `some_path/music` to `/etc/exports` on the ownCloud machine, to be used as an NFS drive (or simply set `data/music/files` as the NFS drive)
4. load `some_path/music` as an NFS drive on the RuneAudio machine

I think that should work, though I am afraid that the RuneAudio machine won't be able to read the contents of `some_path/music` because of special ownCloud permissions. Is that correct? What would then the best solution be? Since I have gigas of music, I don't want to spend two hours uploading it at the wrong place (and in general, I don't want to break thing).

Thanks for your help, any suggestions/solutions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end I didn't even create an account for `music`, and I am serving `data/my_user/files/Music` as an NFS. Everything works well!